# JSON multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am currently working with JSON that I would like to recover in jQuery. Usually, I get there without problems except that this time the JSON has several nested tables. Here is an example:

```js
{
  "test1": [
    [{
        "Val1": "Hello word !",
        "Val2": "Hello word !",
        "Val3": "Hello word !",
        "Val4": "Hello word !",
        "Val5": "Hello word !"
      },
      {
        "Val1": "Hello word !",
        "Val2": "Hello word !",
        "Val3": "Hello word !",
        "Val4": "Hello word !",
        "Val5": "Hello word !"
      }
    ],
    [{
        "Val1": "Hello word !",
        "Val2": "Hello word !",
        "Val3": "Hello word !",
        "Val4": "Hello word !",
        "Val5": "Hello word !"
      },
      {
        "Val1": "Hello word !",
        "Val2": "Hello word !",
        "Val3": "Hello word !",
        "Val4": "Hello word !",
        "Val5": "Hello word !"
      }
    ],
    []
  ]
}
```

When I work with a single table I proceeded as follows:

```
success: function(data) {
    data.test1[1].Val1;
}
```

Except this time there is another picture from my main table and my object. So I tried things like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    data.test1[1][3].Val1;
}
```

```js
success: function(data) {
    data.test1[1].3[3]Val1;
}
```

```js
success: function(data) {
    data.test1[1[3]].Val1;
}
```

Do you have a solution? Thanks you

Comment: Please include some of the JSON in your question. Don't expect people to click away just to see it when you could have added a snippet of it which shows the issue.

Comment: `test1` is an array which has two sub arrays, but only the first has data so use `[0]` to access it. From there you can access the data as usual. For example this returns the `Val1` property of the first object in the first array: `data.test1[0][0].Val1`. If you can give a more clear explanation of what you're trying to achieve then we can offer more useful guidance as to how you can actually use this data structure in your logic.